# Redshift as a Web App Backend?

Tags: django, postgresql, architecture, amazon-redshift

I am building an application (using Django's ORM) that will ingest a lot of events, let's say 50/s (1-2k per msg). Initially some "real time" processing and monitoring of the events is in scope so I'll be using redis to keep some of that data to make decisions, expunging them when it makes sense. I was going to persist all of the entities, including events in Postgres for "at rest" storage for now.

In the future I will need "analytical" capability for dashboards and other features. I want to use Amazon Redshift for this. I considered just going straight for Redshift and skipping Postgres. But I also see folks say that it should play more of a passive role. Maybe I could keep a window of data in the SQL backend and archive to Redshift regularly.

My question is:

Is it even normal to use something like Redshift as a backend for web applications or does it typically play more of a passive role? If not is it realistic to think I can scale the Postgres enough for the event data to start with only that? Also if not, does the "window of data and archival" method make sense?

EDIT Here are some things I've seen before writing the post:

- Some say ["yes go for it"](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Can-AWS-Redshift-be-used-49531.S.5874931438192705544) regarding the should I use Redshift for this question.
- Some say ["eh not performant enough for most web apps"](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-Amazon-Redshift) and support the *front it with a postgres database* camp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redshift (ParAccel) is an OLAP-optimised DB, based on a fork of a very old version of PostgreSQL.

It's good at parallelised read-mostly queries across lots of data. It's bad at many small transactions, especially many small write transactions as seen in typical OLTP workloads.

You're partway in between. If you don't mind a data loss window, then you could reasonably accumulate data points and have a writer thread or two write batches of them to Redshift in decent sized transactions.

If you can't afford any data loss window and expect to be processing 50+ TPS, then don't consider using Redshift directly. The round-trip costs alone would be horrifying. Use a local database - or even a file based append-only journal that you periodically rotate. Then periodically upload new data to Redshift for analysis.

A few other good reasons you probably shouldn't use Redshift directly:

- OLAP DBs with column store designs often work best with star schemas or similar structures. Such schemas are slow and inefficient for OLTP workloads as inserts and updates touch many tables, but they make querying the data along various axes for analysis much more efficient.
- Using an ORM to talk to an OLAP DB is asking for trouble. ORMs are quite bad enough on OLTP-optimised DBs, with their unfortunate tendency toward n+1 `SELECT`s and/or wasteful chained left joins, tendency to do many small inserts instead of a few big ones, etc. This will be even worse on most OLAP-optimised DBs.
- Redshift is based on a painfully old PostgreSQL with a bunch of limitations and incompatibilities. Code written for normal PostgreSQL may not work with it.

Personally I'd avoid an ORM entirely for this - I'd just accumulate data locally in an SQLite or a local PostgreSQL or something, sending multi-valued `INSERT`s or using PostgreSQL's `COPY` to load chunks of data as I received it from an in-memory buffer. Then I'd use appropriate ETL tools to periodically transform the data from the local DB and merge it with what was already on the analytics server.

---

Now forget everything I just said and go do some benchmarks with a simulation of your app's workload. That's the only really useful way to tell.

Comment: Thank you for the detail! I am a little uncomfortable with the local db or file based journal approach though, tho I see the performance benefit. The local file system seems a little risky operationally to store transactions. You think a cache like redis is appropriate for a scale of that size, at least temporarily and load to RS from there?

Comment: @alph486 Well, it depends on how willing you are to lose data, and how long a data loss window you can accept. A local journal is probably going to be safer than an in-memory DB like Redis, but also probably slower.

Comment: Gotcha. Looks like redis' disk persistence can use an append only journal that writes at least every 2 seconds, which I think is an acceptable worst case window. I may be able to get the best of both worlds there and minimize risk. Source: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis

Comment: I'd avoid an ORM entirely for everything. I really do not understand why companies work with such. in the end of the day they cost more

Comment: @Dejell Depends on the workload. Most people who don't use ORMs land up reinventing them sooner or later, badly, as application frameworks. They're practical for simple use, you just need to know when to use one and when not to.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Redshift's slow transaction processing (by modern DB standards) there's another big challenge:

Redshift only supports `serializable` transaction isolation, most likely as a compromise to support ACID transactions while also optimizing for parallel OLAP mostly-read workload.

That can result in all kinds of concurrency-related failures that would not have been failures on typical DB that support read-committed isolation by default.